# What contexts can be used when setting a GitHub Action job name?

Tags: github-actions

I'd like to set a GitHub Action job name using the value of a variable set in the environment, but the following straightforward approach fails with an error about `Unrecognized named-value: 'env'`:

```
env:
  SERVER: https://example.com

...

jobs:
  Send_to_server:
    name: "Send to ${{env.SERVER}}"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
```

In GitHub's documentation, there is [an example of using the `vars` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-usage-of-the-vars-context) and another [example of using the `strategy` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-usage-of-the-strategy-context). Based on the error I get, I guess the `env` context cannot be used in this situation. **What other contexts *can* be used in the definition of the job name?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jobs.<job_id>.name` has `github`, `needs`, `strategy`, `matrix`, `vars` and `inputs` contexts.

---

This is normally written in the documentation as it varies for the different places.

From the link in your question:

> For details of where you can use various contexts within a workflow, see "[Contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability)."

That is linked to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability and titled **Context availability**.

Search the table in that section for location you're interested in.

Comment: I saw that table, but misunderstood the intended sense, and thought the "contexts" were where you can use the values in the first column and not the other way around. Thank you for clarifying it. Now it makes more sense :-).

Comment: Ah, yes, the original meaning of context. "Naming things"... .